# Problema con Botón "Modificar" a registro de JTable en JAVA

Tags: java

Necesito crear un boton que cuando modifico un registro en mi `JTable` este se guarde. Para ello genere el siguiente código dentro de un `Action` performed en mi boton "BtnModificar" y lo que debería hacer guardar las modificaciones que le haga a cualquier registro o fila de mi `JTable`. El problema es que al hacer clic sobre el botón me devuelve el error

> Error: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Ya revise la cantidad de parámetros y está bien, también revise mi statement y funciona en `MySQL`... Intente cambiar la condición del for pero es lo mismo...

Gracias de antemano.

Código:

```
JButton btnModificar = new JButton("Actualizar Registro");
    btnModificar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            connect cc = new connect();
            Connection cn = cc.conectar();
            int filaselect= table.getSelectedRow();
            String cedulaselect=table.getValueAt(filaselect, 0).toString();


            try{
                int[] filasSelec = table.getSelectedRows();
                //for(int i = 0; i <= table.getSelectedRow(); i++)
                for( int i = 0; i < filasSelec.length; i++) {
                    String id = (String) table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i], 0);

                {
                    PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE persona SETnombre='?',apellido='?',tipo='?',telefono='?',contrasena='?',Estado='?')"+ " WHERE pk_ci='?'");
                    pst.setString(1, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],0).toString());
                    pst.setString(2, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],1).toString());
                    pst.setString(3, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],2).toString());
                    pst.setString(4, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],3).toString());
                    pst.setString(5, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],4).toString());
                    pst.setString(6, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],5).toString());
                    pst.setString(7, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],6).toString());
                    if(pst.executeUpdate() > 0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "dato guardado correctamente");
                    }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido realizar la actualización de los datos\n"
                                + "Inténtelo nuevamente.", "Error en la operación", 
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                }}catch (Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+e1.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
    btnModificar.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ventana_crearusuario.class.getResource("/images/rotate.png")));
    btnModificar.setBounds(7, 515, 175, 45);
    contentPane.add(btnModificar);
```

### Luego de rastrear donde estaba el problema en la ejecución del código llegue a que el problema se origina en alguna parte dentro del siguiente código. Ya que lo anterior al código que indico a continuación lo ejecuta sin problemas.

La parte del código que contiene el problema es

```
pst.setString(1, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],0).toString());
                    pst.setString(2, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],1).toString());
                    pst.setString(3, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],2).toString());
                    pst.setString(4, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],3).toString());
                    pst.setString(5, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],4).toString());
                    pst.setString(6, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],5).toString());
                    pst.setString(7, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],6).toString());
```

Se actualizó el código y ya no devuelve el error... Pero no guarda el cambio en la BBDD.

```
PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement "UPDATE persona SET pk_ci=?, nombre=? ,apellido=? ,tipo=? ,telefono=? ,contrasena=? ,Estado=?"+ " WHERE pk_ci=?";
                    System.out.println("prepare Statement ejecutado");
                    pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],0).toString()));
                    pst.setString(2, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],1).toString());
                    pst.setString(3, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],2).toString());
                    pst.setString(4, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],3).toString());
                    pst.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],4).toString()));
                    pst.setString(6, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],5).toString());
                    pst.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],6).toString()));
                    System.out.println("obtiene los valores");
```

Comment: En qué linea es donde te marca el error?

Comment: @Sr1871 los rastrie con un systemout y no está entrando a esta parte `PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE persona SET(nombre='?',apellido='?',tipo='?',telefono='?',contrasena='?',Estado='?')"+ " WHERE pk_ci='?'");`

Comment: intenta poniendo los signos de interrogación sin comillas simples, es decir
`cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE persona SET(nombre= ? ,apellido= ? ...`

Comment: Dice que hay algo mal en mi consulta SQL. El problema es que estoy obteniendo y enviando los datos en formato String a la BBDD.

Comment: pk_ci también es string?

Comment: Enla base de datos no, pero ahi lo estoy convirtiendo para obtenerlo de el JTable. En la base de datos se guarda como INT. todo se obtiene y envía como String

Comment: así no funciona, tienes que convertirlo al valor que se va a pasar en la bd, tendrías que hacer algo como `pst.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(tabla.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],6).toString()))`

Comment: Bien lo que hice fue convertir a Integer aquellos datos que en la base son Integer. Adicionalmente le quite las comillas simples del statement. Ahora ya no tira el error y al hacer la prueba devuelve "dato guardado correctamente" es decir ejecuta todo el código **pero no guarda el cambio en la BBDD** por lo tanto debe haber algo mal en mi statement que quedó de la siguiente manera. (ver actualización en la pregunta al principio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto,

Finalmente para resolver el problema se tuvieron que crear 2 variables una de tipo entero que hiciera referencia a la fila seleccionada y otra de tipo String que hiciera referencia al indice cero de la fila seleccionada en mi JTable. El problema radica en que el statement en la parte del WHERE no se está indicando un valor por el cual pueda ejecutarse la consulta en la BBDD:

Código

```
JButton btnModificar = new JButton("Actualizar Registro");
    btnModificar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            connect cc = new connect();
            Connection cn = cc.conectar();
            int filaci= table.getSelectedRow();
            String valorci=table.getValueAt(filaci, 0).toString();



            try{
                int[] filasSelec = table.getSelectedRows();
                //for(int i = 0; i <= table.getSelectedRow(); i++)
                for( int i = 0; i < filasSelec.length; i++) {
                    String id = (String) table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i], 0);
                    System.out.println("For ejecutado");

                {
                    PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE persona SET pk_ci=?, nombre=?, apellido=? ,tipo=? ,telefono=? ,contrasena=? ,Estado=? WHERE pk_ci="+valorci+"");
                    System.out.println("prepare Statement ejecutado");
                    pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],0).toString()));
                    pst.setString(2, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],1).toString());
                    pst.setString(3, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],2).toString());
                    pst.setString(4, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],3).toString());
                    pst.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],4).toString()));
                    pst.setString(6, table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],5).toString());
                    pst.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i],6).toString()));
                    System.out.println("obtiene los valores");

                    if(pst.executeUpdate() > 0){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "dato guardado correctamente");
                        }else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido realizar la actualización de los datos\n"
                                    + "Inténtelo nuevamente.", "Error en la operación", 
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                }
                }
        }catch (Exception e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+e1.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
    btnModificar.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ventana_crearusuario.class.getResource("/images/rotate.png")));
    btnModificar.setBounds(7, 515, 175, 45);
    contentPane.add(btnModificar);
```